# Jquery to Javascript Bootstrap Scroll Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, navigation, nav

ive been trying to convert this jquery to JS and I can't figure it out. Could someone help me out here is the jquery. When scrolling it is supposed to toggle the effect as I move, but its not working and I would like to learn how it would be done in javascript.

```
 $(function () {     
$(document).scroll(function () { 
var $nav = $("#mainNavbar");        
 $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height()); 
}); 
})
```

Comment: all you need is add to index.html this: <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this in Javascript

```
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("myP").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myP").className = "";
  }
}
```